# The @QueryResult doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 4 (SDN4)，And trying to return more than one entities using the @QueryResult

There is no exception thrown，but everything is null in the @QueryResult object
The model is simple as (:User)-[:ROLE]-(:Role)

Does any one know what is the root cause?

The User model

```
@NodeEntity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String userId; 

    @Relationship(type="ROLE")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();   

    public ADUser getaDUser() {
        return aDUser;
    }
    public void setaDUser(ADUser aDUser) {
        this.aDUser = aDUser;
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



}
```

The Role Model

```
@NodeEntity
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {

    @GraphId Long id;

    private String name;

    public Role(){}
    public Role(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }

}
```

The QueryResult

```
@QueryResult
public class UserPermission {

     private User user;
     private  List<Role> roles;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }
}
```

The UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends  GraphRepository<User>{

    public User findByUserId(String userId);

    @Query(" Match (u:User)-[:ROLE]->(r) return u as user , collect(r) as roles ")
    public UserPermission findUserWithRoles();

}
```

And the log is

```
        2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  Neo4jSession:461 - --------- new request ----------
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  Neo4jSession:461 - getOrCreateTransaction() being called on thread: 1
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  Neo4jSession:461 - Session identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@1dcfae07
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  Neo4jSession:461 - There is no existing transaction, creating a transient one
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  DefaultRequest:57 - POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"Match (u:User)-[:ROLE]->(r) return u as user , collect(r) as roles","parameters":{},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  DefaultRequest:86 - Response is OK, creating response handler
2015-08-05 17:56:18 WARN  SingleUseEntityMapper:97 - Unable to find property: roles on class: model.UserPermission for writing
2015-08-05 17:56:18 WARN  SingleUseEntityMapper:97 - Unable to find property: user on class: model.UserPermission for writing
2015-08-05 17:56:18 INFO  JsonResponse:103 - Closing HttpResponse
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no support at the moment to map entities into a `@QueryResult`.
So instead of returning `User` and `Role` you'll have to return user id's and role id's and then hydrate them using `load` for example.

Alternatively, if you're looking for a simple way to find users by roles, you might try a method such as 
`List<User> findByRolesName(String roleName)` on the `UserRepository`

Comment: Is this supported in recent `4.0.1` snapshots? If not, are there plans to implement this feature at all? The docs say it isn't supported *yet*, but we're five months past GA and I don't even see an open issue related to implementing it. Being able to map complex query results to POJOs is at the top of my list of cool things SDN3 can do, and I see it as a major regression that SDN4 doesn't support it.

Comment: This is on the roadmap, there's an issue already open: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-700